# Funciona no NetBeans mas não no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

O seguinte código funciona para quando o user deixa em branco um editText do formulário. O código funcionou no NetBeans mas no AndroidStudio quando roda o APK com um campo em branco ele aparece a mensagem que o APP parou de funcionar.
Segue o código:

//No NetBeans

```
BigDecimal cota = null;
BigDecimal prazo = null;
BigDecimal reserva = null;
BigDecimal adm = null;

try {
    cota = new BigDecimal(jTextField1.getText());
    prazo = new BigDecimal(jTextField2.getText());
    reserva = new BigDecimal(jTextField3.getText());
    adm = new BigDecimal(jTextField4.getText());

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    jLabel5.setText("Os valores não podem estar vazios!");
}
```

//No Android

```
BigDecimal cota = null;
            BigDecimal prazo = null;
            BigDecimal reserva = null;
            BigDecimal adm = null;
            BigDecimal vida = null;



try{
                cota = new BigDecimal(edtCota.getText().toString());
                prazo = new BigDecimal(edtPrazo.getText().toString());
                reserva = new BigDecimal(edtReserva.getText().toString());
                adm = new BigDecimal(edtAdm.getText().toString());
                vida = new BigDecimal(edtVida.getText().toString());

            }catch(NumberFormatException erro){

                AlertDialog.Builder janelaVazio = new AlertDialog.Builder(Consorcio.this);
                janelaVazio.setMessage("Preencha todos os campos");
                janelaVazio.setNeutralButton("FECHAR", null);
                janelaVazio.show();
            }
```

Comment: Adicionei pra ve  se corrigia mas não mudou nada. Ele estava igual o do netBeans mudando apenas a saida da mensagem

Comment: O erro acontece antes ou depois de dialog ser apresentado? Que erro é que dá?

Comment: O dialog nem chega a ser apresentado. O que aparece é que o app parou de funcionar e reinicia. Foi exatamente por isso que usei o try e catch pra tentar corrigir isto, no NetBeans funcionou ok já no android continua

Comment: O facto de algum EditText estar em branco é capturado pelo try, O que pode estar a acontecer é algum dos atributos `edXXX` ser nulo.

Comment: Altere NumberFormatException para Exception para analisarmos outro tipo de erro.

Comment: Não funciona no android Studio nem na bala